# How to fetch value from one input into another?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

Hi all I want to fetch the input value from `Buyer_name`  into `Copied Buyer_name` input field.i tried many ways but unable to find the solution if anyone knows the solution please help me....[my plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qI1ozFmPQmdviWIBRa1B?p=preview)

**controller:-**

```
$('#supname').change(function() {
$('#supnamecopy').val($(this).val());

});
```

**Html:-**

```
 <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="state.quantity" id="quantity" typeahead="state as state.quantity for state in states | filter: $viewValue">

 <label for="quantity">Buyer_name</label>
      <input type="text" id="supname" ng-model="state.quantity" typeahead="state.buyer_name  for state in states | filter: $viewValue">

 <label for="quantitycopy">Copied Buyer_name</label>
      <input type="text" name="supnamecopy" id="supnamecopy" ng-model="copied">
```

**My Data:-**

```
    $scope.states = [{
"_id": "5744009c2f0f2bef0ca707ef",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"description_count": "check",
"description_quality": "new",
"__v": 1,
"created": "2016-05-24T07:19:56.471Z",
"cone": "pending",
"status": "pending",
"currency": "Rs",
"unit": "KG",
"price": [
"500",
"400"
],
"actual_devlivery_date": "2016-05-2",
"ex_india_date": "2016-05-24",
"quantity_unit": "KG",
"quantity": "34",
"enquiry_received_date": "2016-05-24",
"supplier_name": "Mani selvam",
"buyer_name": "Rohit"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/VIZkyM08IKuSChL5vvOL?p=preview

HTML - remains as is

JS - changed jQuery to angular functionality.

The way your ng-model is set at the moment assigns the $scope.state.quantity as the selected state rather than the quantity value from that state.

```
$scope.$watch('state.quantity', function() {
    if($scope.state && $scope.state.quantity && $scope.state.quantity.buyer_name) {
        $scope.copied = angular.copy($scope.state.quantity.buyer_name);
    } else {
        $scope.copied = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!!! .......actually i was used type ahead in quantity, if i select quantity value simultaneously the buyer name need fetch and need copied buyer_name values also.....[my plunk] (plnkr.co/edit/yZ8h2G1BDolfwrkGkP4F?p=preview) please help me for the same.....  for example:- if i select quantity is 34, buyer_name is fetched automatically Rohit.....what i exactly need the buyer_name input need to fetch into copied buyer_name also....

Comment: Updated answer above to meet your needs I think

Comment: Hi Rian if you able to provide the  plunker which is easily (helpful and understand) to me..!!!!

Comment: The link is at the top of the answer

Comment: @R. Mani Selvam. You're welcome. Please tick the answer if it solved your issue

Comment: i have the same issues with different  set of data  pls look at this link(http://plnkr.co/edit/gfNKpAdmnxFhJRyLFq1e?p=preview). pls help me with this issue. thanks

Comment: please follow this link as well :- (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078410/how-can-i-fetch-the-value-from-one-input-field-into-another-field)

Answer (score 0):

try this. this shall give you a live preview of the copy as well

```
<label for="quantity">Buyer_name</label>
      <input type="text" id="supname" ng-model="state.quantity" typeahead="state.buyer_name  for state in states | filter: $viewValue">

 <label for="quantitycopy">{{state.quantity}}</label>
      <input type="text" name="supnamecopy" id="supnamecopy" ng-model="copied">
```